# Modal popup used to show up, no longer does in any browser

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

Here is the page in question: https://www.matejkadesign.com/pricing.php

When you click on the "what's this" icons, an exitable modal popup should fade in on the same page. It has been broken since 2 days ago (It does not pop up in any browser). Has there been some browser/coding upgrade done to disable my code? I checked with my Web-host, and they cannot help me.

If you view page source, you will find the code for my Modal boxes at the bottom, and you'll be able to see where they are linked to for activating them.

I would appreciate it if somebody could look into it. I'm half expecting people to say something like "but the modal boxes work for me, it must be just your computer." It would be great if that were the case, I have no way of knowing.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the console, `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js` returns 404. When the "what's this" is clicked, the Console shows the error `$ is not defined`, which also tells us that jQuery never loaded.
The `https` version of the page currently has an incorrect security certificate, so if you use `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js`, you'll be fine.

Comment: This is helpful. But what do you mean by an incorrect security certificate? Do you mean that it cannot support https for that jquerry link? When my host setup the certificate, I was told I might have problems if I don't switch everything to https.

Comment: The way I fixed it was by copying the code from the original source and putting it into my own .js file. This way, I could securely call it by https from my own server.

Comment: Incorrect security certificate is required for https connections. If it is incorrect in any way, the browser will not load the page without the user's approval. If it is a script or other referenced file in another page, the user will not see this request for approval, and you see a 404.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the jquery web-site. I would just put these into your page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Which come from google.

Comment: The way I fixed it was by copying the code from the original source and putting it into my own .js file. This way, I could securely call it by https from my own server.